# How to insert arbitrary number of links in a gridview cell?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm populating a gridview using a table and there is column which holds link IDs.
There can by many link IDs in the same cell.
If the cell contains one link ID then it works fine. The challenge is to support arbitrary number of links on the same cell.
My code:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="CWEID"
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/{0}.html"
DataTextField="CWEID" HeaderText="CWE ID" Target="_blank"/>
```

The cell value retrieved from table can be: [770\n838\n120], thus the cell should show 3 links for each ID.
I searched around, and it seems we can do it statically but not for arbitrary number of links.
Any pointers on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to replace `HyperLinkField` with `TemplateField` and nested `Repeater` inside.
There is example :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CWE ID">
 <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptLinks" DataSource='<%# Eval("CWEID").ToString.Replace("\n", "").Split(" ")%>'>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <a href="https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/<%# Container.DataItem%>.html" target="_blank"><%# Container.DataItem%></a>
      <br />
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>  
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

`Repeater` will split `CWEID` (with `\n`, I think that is `vbCrLf` in vb.net so You can replace `\n` with `vbCrLf`, without double quotes) record and place all links in separated `<a href...`. You'll get all links in that cell. There is no matter how many links are stored into `CWEID` (one or more).

So, result will be (for example) :

```
<a href="..../770.html" target="_blank">770</a><br>
<a href="..../838.html" target="_blank">838</a><br>
<a href="..../120.html" target="_blank">120</a><br>
```

Ot just one link, depend how many links You have in `CWEID`.

*UPDATE :*

Code changed for `DataSource` to `<%# Eval("CWEID").ToString.Replace("\n", " ").Split(" ")%>`

Comment: Thanks! It works! I didn't know about repeaters. There is a small problem, the IDs are appearing like 770 n838 n120, which I'm trying to debug.

Comment: Solved the issue:  

`DataSource='<%# Replace(Container.DataItem("CWEID"), "\n", " ").ToString.Split(" ")%>'`

Answer (score 0):

You could add a handler to the gridview's RowDataBound event.  In that event you have the ability to modify the contents of any of the cells being rendered in the current row of the gridview, including the ability to create new HTML elements and insert them.  In the code below I'm adding an icon to the first cell in a gridview if the current row has child data to be shown.

```
'New Bootstrap style toggle button for details view
Dim toggle As New HtmlGenericControl("i")
With toggle
   .Attributes("class") = "icon-plus icon-white"
   .Attributes("onclick") = "javascript: gvrowtoggle(" & e.Row.RowIndex + (e.Row.RowIndex + 2) & ")"
   .Attributes("id") = "toggleBttn"
End With
```

Then I append the new control to the first cell in the current row:

`e.Row.Cells(0).Controls.Add(toggle)`